# How to runCommand() of a bash script with redirected input from file in Mozilla Rhino?

Tags: javascript, bash, rhino

Is it possible to execute external bash script and set another file as input for it using Rhino?
e.g. I need to rewrite bash script(exec.sh) with following content:

```
somescript.sh <fileInput.txt
```

I've tried many ways but without success:

1. Reading fileInput.txt as input stream and passing to shell:

   var inputStream = new java.io.InputStream(fileInput.txt);
   runCommand( "somescript.sh", inputStream);
2. Writing `"somescript.sh <fileInput.txt"` to additional bash script and calling runCommand():

   message = new FileUtils.writeStringToFile(helpfulScript, "somescript.sh 
   runCommand("bash", helpfulScript.getCanonicalPath());

Sorry for pure highlight and thanks in advice for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the input stream in as the `input` property of an object.

```
var inputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream("fileInput.txt");
runCommand("somescript.sh", { input: inputStream });
```

If `input` is not an `InputStream` it will be converted to a string and sent to the command directly. Similarly, you can add `output` and/or `err` properties to capture the command's standard output and standard error ([documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Shell#runCommand.28commandName.2C_.5Barg.2C_....5D_.5Boptions.5D.29)).

Comment: Perfect! BTW the documentation doesn't scope the way how streams should be passed ;(